# Can't add title to reference in achemso bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

I'm trying to submit an article to The Journal of Physical Chemistry, using acshemso template at [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com).
There are no titles of the references, but it's necessary according to journal rules.

I changed ctrl-article-title to "yes" in acs-achemso.bib file of the template:

```
 @Control{achemso-control,
  ctrl-article-title  = "yes",
  ctrl-chapter-title  = "no",
  ctrl-etal-number    = "15",
  ctrl-etal-firstonly = "yes",
```

Nothing changed.

I tried to use package downloaded by the [link](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso) from author guidelines, but it also without the titles of the references.

Please, help me. It's my first time using Tex, so I can't imagine what can I do to manage appearance of references titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article titles are not included by default. You have to specify what sort of journal you are writing for, then the `achemso` package will adapt the document style according to its guidelines.

For example, if you are writing an article for the "Journal of Physical Chemistry A", you should have this at the start of your document:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcafh]{achemso}
```

The list of available journals can be found on page 4 of [the `achemso` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso.pdf).

Here is a full working example:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcafh]{achemso}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
Test \cite{myreference}
\bibliography{achs_jpcafh121_7139}
\end{document}
```

with a random reference:

```
@article{myreference,
    author = {Jåstad, Eirik O. and Torheim, Turid and Villeneuve, Kathleen M. and Kvaal, Knut and Hole, Eli O. and Sagstuen, Einar and Malinen, Eirik and Futsaether, Cecilia M.},
    title = {In Quest of the Alanine R3 Radical: Multivariate EPR Spectral Analyses of X-Irradiated Alanine in the Solid State},
    journal = {The Journal of Physical Chemistry A},
    volume = {121},
    number = {38},
    pages = {7139-7147},
    year = {2017},
    doi = {10.1021/acs.jpca.7b06447},
    note ={PMID: 28829916},
    URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpca.7b06447},
    eprint = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpca.7b06447}
}
```

Result:

[image: References]

Comment: I've changed default [journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}  to \documentclass[journal=jpcafh,manuscript=article]{achemso}  and it works! 
@SDF, thank you so much!

Comment: @obogomol You're welcome ;-) If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). By the way, I see it's your first time here, so welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Editorial guidelines for journals change in time. In some, the article title was 
not required previously, but is required now. In some, "et al." was required after 10 authors, now all authors must be listed.

In ACS journals, this should be handled by the achemso package automatically. But the
package is not updated too often, and behavior must be changed from the default.
Example:

```
\documentclass[journal=nalefd,manuscript=letter,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}

specifies the proper journal (Nano Letters) and the layout. Add the following 
two lines below if needed:

\setkeys{acs}{maxauthors = 0}      % will list all authors

\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true} % will suppress showing article title
```

Comment: If `achemso` deviates from documented requirements you can open an issue at https://github.com/josephwright/achemso/issues